Parse Minecraft's VarInt
If you look at the reverse-engineered Minecraft Java Edition server protocol, there is an interesting integer encoding method that is used quite often called VarInt.
It works like this:
You have an array of bytes. The last 7 bits of each byte is used to encode part of the integer, with the high bit determining whether to continue to the next byte. The 7-bit sections are then concatenated into
For example, given the bytes 0xdd, 0xc7, 0x01, 0x47:
   0xdd       0xc7       0x01       0x47
1 1011101  1 1000111  0 0000001  0 1000111

The dd and c7 bytes have their high bits set, so we continue on to the next bytes, but the 01 byte does not, so we stop there and ignore the 47. Then, the remaining bits are concatenated into a single little-endian 32-bit integer:
0000001 1000111 1011101 = 25565

The result should be treated as a signed two's complement 32-bit integer - if the high (31st) bit is set, the remaining bits should be negated and have 1 subtracted. You can assume the result will always fit in a 32-bit integer - If a VarInt has five bytes, the 4 most significant bits of the last byte will not be set.
You can find more information about the protocol on the reverse engineering wiki.
Examples:
0x00: 0
0x81, 0x00: 1
0x7f, 0x00, 0x34: 127
0xDD, 0xC7, 0x01: 25,565
0xFF, 0xFF, 0x7F: 2,097,151
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x07: 2147483647
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x0F: -1
0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x08: -2,147,483,648
0xFF, 0xFE, 0x43, 0xFF, 0x02: 1113983
Method:
Here is an ungolfed method of doing this in JavaScript:
function parseVarInt(varInt) {
  let result = 0;
  let shift = 0;
  for(let byte of varInt) { // loop over every byte
    result |= (byte & 0x7F) << shift; // add the current 7 bits onto the pre-existing result
    shift += 7;
    if(!(byte & 0x80)) { // if the continue bit isn't enabled, break.
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

Rules & Info:

This is a codegolfing challenge! Least amount of bytes win.
Return value can be in any format, but it must be some form of number
Functions count as a program. If you have a function with an input and a return value, that is as good as having a program which outputs directly to console
Bonus points* if you can also convert an integer to a VarInt!
Standard loopholes are not allowed.
The input can be any form of array of bits or bytes.
Though it does have it on the wiki, you do not need to have error parsing. Assume that all VarInts are a max of 5 bytes long.
* For cool factor only


Will we be given inputs such as 0x81, 0x00, 0x81, where there are bytes after the break bit that we have to ignore? If so, I'd recommend adding a relevant test case.

Yes, thank you for the advice!

Doesn't 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x43, 0xFF, 0x32 evaluate to 1113983? (same as 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x43)

It does indeed! Thank's for the notice, I think I have a bug in my golfed code!

This needs to be clearer as to the expected inputs and outputs rather than trying to infer them from they examples.

for the last byte, only the 3 least-significant bits are used -> Did you mean the 4 least significant bits? Otherwise, we only get 31 bits and your 3rd test case would be invalid.

@Xcali Maybe it should appear in a separate section, but don't rules 2 and 6 make this clear enough?

Added more test cases that test the last couple of significant bits, also updated explanation for clarity (the 3 was a typo)

Actually, looking at the minecraft protocol, it doesn't matter if it's able to handle VarInts with those last 4 bits, as technically they never get sent in-game. Since I'm going to assume that the vanilla MC client does not send corrupted packets, I have removed that rule.

I added a worked example. Feel free to edit / roll it back if it's incorrect.

do we get to take input as parsed ints? as in, if the inputs are [0x7f, 0x00, 0x34], can i take input as [127, 0, 34]?

You've stated "The result should be treated as a signed two's complement 32-bit integer", yet you've accepted the Uiua answer which results in an unsigned value. E.g. Test case 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x0F results in 4294967295 instead of -1. So is a signed 32-bit value as result mandatory or optional?

why was the question edited? the previous iteration didn't require a sign bit. i'll edit my answer but it feels like a major thing to just add on.

I didn't notice the Uiua one didn't correctly deal with signed integers. Yes it is a requirement. There was a signed test case from the start.

And @Themoonisacheese yes, as long as the values represent an array of bytes

oh also @emanresuA thanks for the clarifications! It is an accurate explanation.

"If a varint has five bytes, the 2nd, 3rd and 4th bits of the last byte will not be set." The examples like 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x07: 2147483647 don't match this. 0x07 has its 2nd bit set.

That was from a clarification edit a while back. Fixed now. The 4 MSBs shouldn't be set if it is the 5th byte

F#, 77 bytes
let rec p s (x::r)=x&&&127y|>int<<<s|||if-128y&&&x=0y then 0 else p(s+7)r
p 0

Try it online!
A function expression that takes input as a list of signed bytes and outputs a 64-bit signed int.
Commented
let rec p s (x :: r) = // recursive function p that takes the bit shift amount
                       // and deconstructs a byte list to the first byte x and the tail r
  x &&& 127y |> int    // convert the current byte's end to a signed int
  <<< s                // and shift it by s
  ||| if -128y &&& x = 0y then 0 // OR the value with 0 if the first bit is 0
      else p (s + 7) r           // otherwise repeat this process for the tail
p 0                    // apply the initial shift level to the full function


JavaScript (ES6),  35  34 bytes
f=([v,...a])=>v&&v^(v&=128)|v*f(a)

Try it online!
Commented
f = (      // f is a recursive function taking:
  [ v,     //   v   = next byte from input array
    ...a ] //   a[] = remaining bytes
) =>       //
v          // stop if v is zero or undefined
&&         // otherwise, get the 7 least significant bits of v
v ^        // by XOR'ing v ...
(v &= 128) // ... with its MSB
           // and update v to its MSB
|          // merge this with ...
v *        // ... v (which is now 0x00 or 0x80) multiplied by
f(a)       // the result of a recursive call


Python, 143 137 135 126 bytes
lambda x,s=-7,r=0,c=0:(lambda y:y-(y>2147483647)*4294967296)(sum((r|(b&127)<<(s:=s+7)+0*(c:=b<128))if not c else 0for b in x))

Attempt This Online!
(-6 bytes thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen)
(-2 bytes thanks to @Jordan)
(-9 bytes after I realized I could refactor how lambda y worked, inspired by @Kevin Cruijssen's changing hex to dec)
First time trying code golf. Maybe I shouldn't have chosen parsing bits my first golf ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Nice first answer, +1 from me. You can save 6 bytes with the following minor changes: 0x80000000 else can be 2147483648else for -1 byte on the space; 0x100000000, 0x7F, and 0x80 can be 4294967296, 127, and 128 respectively for -1 byte each; ==0 can be <1 for -1 byte; and you can remove the space at else 0for for another -1 byte. :)

I believe you can also remove the f= from your byte count since the function is not recursive.

@Jordan how would I go about putting that change into the attempt this online? I've never used it before

@TheLittlePeace You can put it into the "Header" section like so.

Japt, 10 bytes
Adheres to the OP's original, albeit severely lacking, spec which didn't require support for outputting negative values.
Takes input as a 2D-array of binary digits.
óÈvÃÎÔc ì2

Try it (Includes all test cases)
23 bytes
This version does include support for negative outputs. Will try to golf it further if it's confirmed we actually need to support them.
óÈvÃÎÔc ì2
2pH
¨Vz
-V*W

Try it
óÈvÃÎÔc ì2\n2pH\n¨Vz\n-V*W     :Implicit input of array U
ó                              :Partition after sub-arrays that return falsey (0)
 È                             :When passed through this function
  v                            :  Pop & return the first element, mutating the sub-array
   Ã                           :End partition
    Î                          :First element
     Ô                         :Reverse
      c                        :Flatten
        ì2                     :Convert from binary
          \n                   :Reassign that to variable U
            2p                 :2 raised to the power of
              H                :  32
               \n              :Assign that to variable V
                 ¨             :U is greater than or equal to
                  Vz           :  V (floor) divided by 2
                    \n         :Assign that to variable W
                      -V*W     :Subtract V*W from U


Minecraft Function, 431 bytes
scoreboard objectives add a dummy
scoreboard players set c a 128
execute unless score a a < m a run scoreboard players set m a 1
execute store result score a a run data get storage x x[0]
data remove storage x x[0]
execute if score a a >= c a run schedule function p:f 1 
scoreboard players operation a a %= c a
scoreboard players operation a a *= m a
scoreboard players operation v a += a a
scoreboard players operation m a *= c a

This question wouldn't be complete without a Minecraft solution.
Run as a function named f in a data pack named p. Input is given as a list of bytes in array x of storage x, and can be set like so:
/data modify storage x x set value [221,199,1,71]

Output is given as the scoreboard value for player v of objective a, and can be viewed with:
/scoreboard players get v a

The function first sets up a scoreboard for holding variables, sets c = 128 and m = 1, then iterates over each byte a, performing these operations:

Reduce a modulo c
Multiply a by m
Add a to the total v
Multiply m by 128

This builds up the value 7 bits at a time. The function terminates one iteration after it finds an a less than c (equivalent to not having its high bit set). Minecraft stores scoreboard values as 32 bit signed integers, so they roll over appropriately for negative numbers.

05AB1E, 21 (or 12) bytes
η.Δθн_}€¦RJCDžI&ĀžJ*-

Input as a list of binary-strings (e.g. example 0xdd,0xc7,0x01,0x47. is input as ["11011101","11000111","00000001","01000111"])
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
Step 1: Main part of the challenge:
η          # Get the prefixes of the (implicit) input-list
 .Δ        # Find the first prefix that's truthy for:
   θ       #  Pop and leave the last string of the current prefix
    н      #  Pop and leave its first bit
     _     #  Check that it's 0
  }€       # After the find_first: map over each prefix:
    ¦      #  Remove its first bit
     R     # Reverse this list of prefixes
      J    # Join them together
       C   # Convert it from a binary-string to a base-10 integer

Try just step 1 online for all test cases.
Step 2: Convert the unsigned to signed 32-bit integers:
D          # Duplicate the current value
   &       # Bitwise-AND it with
 žI        # constant value 2147483648
    Ā      # Check whether this is NOT 0
       *   # Multiply this 0 or 1 by
     žJ    # constant value 4294967296
        -  # Subtract that from the value of step 1
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)


Not entirely sure how to do the necessary construction in osabie but it might be shorter to index into [0, 1, 2, ..., 2^32 - 1, -1, -2, ..., -2^32 + 1, -2^32]

@emanresuA Unfortunately it's way too slow to create that list on TIO. Although I think it's also actually 1 byte longer, where the second step would become žILD<s(«sè. Unless you can find a -2 bytes when constructing that list instead of žILD<s(«.

Uiua, 15 bytes
°⋯♭▽≤⊗0:°⊏≡⍜⇌°⊂

Takes input as an array of 8-bit bytes (lsb-first)
Try it!
°⋯♭▽≤⊗0:°⊏≡⍜⇌°⊂
          ≡⍜⇌°⊂ # pull the msb from each row
       :°⊏      # range by the length under the msbs
     ⊗0         # find the first 0
   ▽≤           # keep the rows <= to its location
°⋯♭             # flatten and convert from binary


C, 44 bytes
p(char*x){return*x&127|(*x>>7?p(x+1)<<7:0);}

Attempt This Online!
Input is a char array, decoded recursively and returned as platform native int type. Negative values work correctly on platforms where int is 32 bits (which includes most current platforms such as ARM and x86_64).

Suggest *x<0 instead of *x>>7

@ceilingcat Good idea! It won't work on platforms with unsigned char, though that is used only by Linux on ARM currently.

APL+WIN, 42 bytes
Prompts for bytes as a nested vector.
((-2*32)×↑i)+2⊥i←¯32↑∊⌽(×\¯1↓1,↑¨b)/1↓¨b←⎕

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Go, 89 bytes
func(B[]byte)(o int32){for i,b:=range B{o+=int32(b&127)<<(i*7)
if b&128<1{break}}
return}

Attempt This Online!
Input is a byte slice, and outputs a 32-bit integer.

I don't think this is an issue with your function, rather an issue with your printing code, but I'm not seeing anything outputted other than the ===START=== and ===FINISH===

@ThePlaneGuy45 It's part of my test harness; it only prints when the expected value doesn't match the actual value, so it only showing START and END like that means that all test cases pass.

Ah, sorry. I'm not very familiar with GO.

Jelly, 17 bytes
ḣṪ€i0ƊFUḄNæ%Ø%H¤N

Try it online!
Input as a list of bit lists, LSB first.
ḣ  i Ɗ               Remove all elements after the first element which
 Ṫ€                  has a last element (MSB)
   i0                equal to 0,
 Ṫ€                  and remove every element's last element.
      F              Flatten,
       U             reverse,
        Ḅ            convert from binary.
         N      N    Under negation,
          æ%         "symmetric modulo"
            Ø%       2^32
              H¤     divided by 2.

"Symmetric modulo 2y" maps into the half-open interval (-y, y] for positive y (and behaving somewhat strangely for negative y). Unfortunately, this interval is open on the wrong end for two's complement representation, so this is corrected by flanking it with Negates.

x86, 24 23 22 bytes
Couldn't figure out any tricks to get rid of shift, so it's a straight-forward do-while loop, checking the byte's sign bit. Input in esi, output in ebx, everything clobbered.
-1 byte by using eax for the t calculations, so I can do 2-byte and al, imm8.
-1 byte by using lodsb instead of mov/inc (but I have to clear upper bits of eax).
parse:                          ; esi input pointer
  31 DB     xor     ebx, ebx    ; ebx result = 0
  31 C9     xor     ecx, ecx    ; ecx shift = 0
.loop:  
  AC        lodsb               ; al byte = [esi++]
  88 C2     mov     dl, al      ; save byte for test later
  83 E0 7F  and     eax, 0x7F   ; t &= 0x7F, clear upper bits
  D3 E0     sal     eax, cl     ; t <<= shift
  09 C3     or      ebx, eax    ; result |= t
  80 C1 07  add     cl, 7       ; shift += 7
  84 D2     test    dl, dl    
  78 EF     js      .loop       ; loop if byte's sign bit is set
  C3        ret                 ; return in ebx   

I formatted all above manually from a NASM listing. Please tell me if there's an easier way.
